# Does order within push constant structs matter, even when using alignas()?

Tags: vulkan

I have a "Sprite" struct that I hand over as a push constant.

```
struct Sprite
{   
    glm::vec2 position;
    alignas(16) Rect uvRect; //a "Rect" is just 2 glm::vec2s
    alignas(4) glm::uint32 textureIndex;
    alignas(4) glm::float32 rotation;
};
```

In my .vert file, I describe its layout as:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform Push
{
    vec2 offset; //the 'position' part of the Sprite
    vec2 origin; //The first part of the Sprite struct's "uvRect"
    vec2 extent; //The second part of the Sprite struct's "uvRect"
    uint textureIndex;
    float rotation;
}
push;
```

This doesn't work: I get a black screen.

However, if I rearrange Sprite so that it goes:

```
struct Sprite
{   
    glm::vec2 position;
    alignas(4) glm::uint32 textureIndex;
    alignas(16) Rect uvRect; //a "Rect" is just 2 glm::vec2s
    alignas(4) glm::float32 rotation;
};
```

...and then change the layout descriptor thing in the .vert file accordingly, suddenly it does work.
Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first structure you align the `Rect` to the 16 byte boundary, but push constant buffer in vulkan is expecting another `vec2` to be tightly packed. Assuming I'm reading the [alignment spec correctly](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap15.html#interfaces-resources-layout) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20220726130159/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap15.html#interfaces-resources-layout)</sub>, structures are aligned on a multiple of a 16 byte boundary, whereas a 2 component vector has an alignment twice that of its base component.

> An array or structure type has an extended alignment equal to the largest extended alignment of any of its members, rounded up to a multiple of 16.

> A scalar or vector type has an extended alignment equal to its base alignment.

> A two-component vector has a base alignment equal to twice its scalar alignment.

> A scalar of size N has a scalar alignment of N.

Thus the offset in of `uvRect` in C is 16, but in GLSL the offset of `origin` is 8 and `extent` is 16.

By changing the order Vulkan will begin looking for `origin` on the 8 byte alignment, which after 3 dwords would be an offset of 16, which then matches what C is expecting.

Comment: Thank you so much: I didn't realize you first needed to look at how the GLSL side would align its data (with 2 vector2s packed tightly) and then work back from that. I was in the mindset of "Well, a Rect is basically a vec4, so it needs to be aligned to 16 bytes" etc.